# check if exist in database

Tags: asp.net, database, exists

i have a textbox where in its value comes from the jquery function for generating random numbers..Now what i want to do is, to check the value(random numbers) of the checkbox if it exists in the database.If the it exists in the database the generated random numbers will not be posted in the textbox instead it will regenerate new random numbers until it produces a number that is not yet saved in the database..

here is my mark up:

```
<p>
<label>Reference Code:</label>
<span class="field">
<asp:TextBox ID="GenerateCode" runat="server" CssClass="smallinput random" CausesValidation="True" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="txthidden" runat="server" />
<br /><small style="color: red">Please write the code at the back of yours check</small>
</span>
</p>
```

here is my jquery function:

```
        function randomString()
        {
            var chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            var result = '';
            for (var i = 8; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
            return result;
        }

        function generateRandomNumber() {
            var rndStr = randomString();
            $("#<%=GenerateCode.ClientID%>").val(rndStr);
            $("#<%=txthidden.ClientID%>").val(rndStr);

        }

        window.onload = function () {
            generateRandomNumber();
        }
```

and here's how i save it to the database:

```
    string EchequeMaster = ClassEmailCheque.InsertEmailCheque(SenderID, Convert.ToInt32(ddlCurrency.SelectedIndex), Convert.ToDecimal(Amount.Text), ChequeNumber.Text, code2, PendingStatus, DateTime.Now);
```

and here's the code for InsertEmailCheque:

```
        string retEcheque = "";
        string EchequeSQL = "INSERT INTO ServiceVirtualAccountEmailCheck (SenderID, CurrencyID, Amount, ChequeNo, ReferenceNo, Status, DateCreated) "
                          + "VALUES (@SenderID, @CurrencyID, @Amount, @ChequeNo, @ReferenceNo, @Status, @DateCreated)";

        string[] param = { "@SenderID", "@CurrencyID", "@Amount", "ChequeNo", "@ReferenceNo", "@Status", "@DateCreated" };
        object[] paramVal = { SenderID, CurrencyID, Amount, ChequeNo, ReferenceNo, Status, DateCreated };

        try
        {
            ClassDBQuery.ExecNonQuery(EchequeSQL, param, paramVal);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retEcheque = ex.Message;
        }

        return retEcheque;
```

please help..
thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rather generate this number in your stored proc.

Instead of calling the INSERT statement right in ASP, why not create a procedure that will generate the AutoNum and check if it exists in the database then use it if it doesn't?

```
CREATE PROC InsertEmailCheque
(
@SenderID INT, @CurrencyID INT, @Amount FLOAT, @ChequeNo INT, @ReferenceNo NVARCHAR(126), @Status NVARCHAR(MAX), @DateCreated DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AutoNum INT
    DECLARE @IsValid BIT

    SET @IsValid = 0

    WHILE @IsValid = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @AutoNum = CONVERT(NUMERIC(8,0),RAND() * 99999999) + 10000000

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT AutoNum FROM ServiceVirtualAccountEmailCheck WHERE AutoNum = @AutoNum)
            SET @IsValid = 1
    END

    INSERT INTO ServiceVirtualAccountEmailCheck (AutoNum, SenderID, CurrencyID, Amount, ChequeNo, ReferenceNo, [Status], DateCreated)
    VALUES (@AutoNum, @SenderID, @CurrencyID, @Amount, @ChequeNo, @ReferenceNo, @Status, @DateCreated)

    SELECT @AutoNum
END
```

I don't know which column you would use the AutoNum with so I assumed a new column called AutoNum. You can see how I use that AutoNum column to check if the number exists or not then set the `@IsValid` to 1 so that we can break out of the `WHILE LOOP`.

Hope this helps.

ADDITION (For Non-Stored Procedure environment):

```
var _result = ClassDBQuery.ExecuteQuery(@"DECLARE @AutoNum INT
                DECLARE @IsValid BIT

                SET @IsValid = 0

                WHILE @IsValid = 0
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @AutoNum = CONVERT(NUMERIC(8,0),RAND() * 99999999) + 10000000

                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT AutoNum FROM Tests1 WHERE AutoNum = @AutoNum)
                        SET @IsValid = 1
                END

                INSERT INTO Tests1 (AutoNum) VALUES (@AutoNum);

                SELECT @AutoNum");

        lblResult.Text = Convert.ToString(_result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

In the example above I execute the statement and return a dataset, which has 1 column, 1 row. I am sure you can make it return 1 value directly.

This value can then be used and in my case, it is converted into a string and passed to lblResult.

Comment: our project is not using stored procedures.. :(